# Create a distribution

Tags: 8, distributions, console

How is it possible to create a new Drupal distribution based on site that I already built? I've already exported the content types using

`drupal config:export:content:type MYCONTENTTYPE --module MYMODULE`

Drupal console has the following function which may be useful.

https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/generate-profile.html

This following link leads to the current drupal.org documentation on creating a Drupal 8 distribution. It looks like it only shows how to create a distribution manually though.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile

I was hoping that there was something in Drupal console or Composer that would take all the information in my current database and create an installation profile out of it.

**EDIT**

The Drupal [Profile Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/profiler_builder) seems wonderful but current only supports D7.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the drupal.org link above will work. At the bottom of the page there is a section that discusses bringing configuration files into the install directory. You can use Drupal Console (DC) to create the configuration files like this:

```
drupal config:export
```

It will put all the configurations in the public folder unless you specifiy a directory.

https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export.html

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile

**EDIT**

Also, I've added a Drupal.org page has a lot of resources for creating a distribution. On the sidebar it lists common `make` errors and other useful links.

If you check the release download page of your distribution, you can find the Drupal packager error messages if you send a distribution for packaging.

A lot of this needs to be learned by trial and error. I've spent a fair amount of time on this and still haven't gotten the hang of things.

https://www.drupal.org/node/642116

**EDIT**

Also, there appears to be something called [drupalorg_drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg_drush). It's a drush extension that helps build a replica of what drupal.org would do with your distribution files should you upload them to your project's Git repository. However, at the time of this writing, Drupal 8 version is not available.

Comment: I've been working through this "trial and error" part for a few days. It seems that installation profiles do not work with Drupal 8. If you use the doc link that you pasted on building a profile, they simply do not install without errors. If you include all of the modules that you need in the info.yml, the installation complains about those modules not being available. Having a composer file with dependencies does not help. As I see it, there is no way to complete an installation with a profile out of the box without troubleshooting.

Comment: @JasonGlisson this was a real pain I remember. I was able to get by with some hacks.

Comment: If there is any useful documentation you can send my way, that would be great. Nothing on Drupal.org is correct for this or it's lacking something.